# How do you call the same class attribute for multiple instances using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to check if the user is clicking an inventory slot in my pygame. I have created the slots with the names "slot1", "slot2", "slot3" etc, all the way up to "slot13". My question really is; how do I add the number behind "slot" for each iteration?

```
if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
    for i in range(14):
        if mouse_click and inventory_state and slot+str(i).collidepoint(pos):
            inventory.equip_item(inventory.items[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the slots in different variables but in a list. Then you can iterate over this list:

```
for i in range(13):
    if mouse_click and inventory_state and slots[i].collidepoint(pos):
        inventory.equip_item(inventory.items[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community Tripti. for the range upto 13, you can store the value of i in a variable and append with 'slot' for each time. That would solve your problem I guess!